# Expand sidemenu smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a sidemenu that is collapsed on small screens, expand smoothly. However, nothing I've tried so far (such as `slideToggle`, `animate`, or `toggleClass` with `duration`) seems to work without leading to problems that are quite hard for me to solve no matter how hard I try.

Perhaps I didn't implement them in the best possible way, so if you think that I should indeed use one of the solutions that I mentioned above, please tell me how I should go about doing so without crippling the rest of the code as I have.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle health" id="sidebutton">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="fa-alpha"></span>       
          </button>

<div class="col-md-2" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav sidemenu">
      <li><a href="/path/to.html">1</a></li>  
      <li><a href="/path/to.html">2</a></li> 
      <li><a href="/path/to.html">3</a></li> 
      <li><a href="/path/to.html">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="/path/to.html">5</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div> <!-- col -->
```

**JS**

```
var scrollTo;
var prevScrolPos;

$('#sidebutton').click(function () {
    if (!$('.sidemenu').hasClass("current")) {
        // if the menu is hidden, save the current scroll position and scroll to top
        prevScrolPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        scrollTo = 0;
    } else {
        // if the menu is not hidden, scroll to the saved position
        scrollTo = prevScrolPos;
    }

    $('.nodisplay').toggleClass("hidden");
    $('.sidemenu').toggleClass('current');
    $('html,body').scrollTop(scrollTo);
});
```

I have created a demo, though it doesn't seem to work on Firefox:
[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7pQw5zqjTO)

Comment: you could try following css: `.sidemenu { transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out }`. For better answers you should create a codepen demo :)

Comment: I didn't understand that is the problem actually. Also, I don't see any animation function in your code. Can you create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or bin with this problem?

Comment: @anton I forgot to mention that I also tried to use CSS transitions at some point, it didn't really help though. I did use your rule too, just in case, but it didn't work either. I need to find the reason why it doesn't by the way, I just can't really think clearly at the moment.. Thank you very much for your reply anyway. :)

Comment: @MoshFeu I added a demo in my post. Thank you for your comment. :)

Comment: You can check [the code for the <nav>](https://github.com/picnicss/picnic/blob/master/plugins/nav/_plugin.scss) in [Picnic CSS](http://picnicss.com/) to see a pure css solution. Disclaimer: my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it by adding the rules below to *.sidemenu*:

```
height: 0;
-webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
-moz-transition: height 1s ease;
-o-transition: height 1s ease;
transition: height 1s ease;
overflow: hidden;
```

and a height value to .sidemenu.current.

I also had to change the name of the class that the group *.nodiplay* gets in the script, so that I would add the declaration *display: none* to it. If it used the declaration *height: 0* as it normally did before I changed its name, tiny parts at the beginning of it would be visible.

Just in case anyone finds it useful.

As I said to anton, whose answer had the same base as the final solution to my problem, it tool me a while to think clearly.. :)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have class `col-md-2` in your html so I assume you are using bootsrap.
Have a look at this demo for perfect solution:

[side-menu using bootstrap](https://jsbin.com/seqola/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: I'd rather not use off-canvas navigation, because I'm afraid that it would confuse a large portion of my target audience. Thank you very much for your suggestion though, it is indeed a great solution for those who can use it.

Comment: What is that you want to achieve then ?

Comment: I just added a demo in my post -- it will probably explain things better than I would. :)